# How can I get the regional settings of the client to identify the client's decimal separator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to parse a value using parseFloat() which I've read only recognises a decimal point(.) as a separator.  I want to be able to run the page (without the user configuring anything) in the EU where they will naturally use the comma as a separator.

Is this possible? I've googled and it seems that this can't be done which I find odd.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** to replace `,` to `.` , after that you can parse as usual

```
var a="1,02";
console.log(parseFloat(a.replace(',','.')));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However if a UK user enters "100,22" this is a invalid value but the above approach will validate it. Is there a way for my script to know what the correct decimal separator is for the user based on settings s/he has on their device?